# VPS networking and routing

Tags: networking, internet, vps

I live in Iran and as you may know these days, we have many problems to use the Internet. I need help about my network and I will appreciate if you can help me.

I have 2 VPS; one of them is out of Iran and the other one is in Iran. When our internet restrict is inbound servers, we just access .ir domains. In this situation, I can reach to my Iran VPS but I cannot connect to my outbound VPS. However, I can use Remote Desktop to reach outbound VPS when I am on my Iran VPS. But the problem is that I can use internet only on my computer.

I want to know how I can transfer my outbound internet to my Iran VPS and then share it whit other devices like smartphone. I try to establish VPN connection, but when I connect VPN in my Iran VPS, I lose all connection even my connection to Iran VPS.

Comment: We really need more information about what os, what protocol, what router (and if you can replace/supplement your router with additional hardware)what you have tried before we can help.

Comment: Thank you in first place. In fact I don't use any special hardware. I just use my computer and my WiFi modem to connect to my VPSs. Also the type of protocol is not important for me. To tell you the truth, I am not really expert in networking I just know some essentials about networking. All I want is find a way to connect to inbound VPS to my outbound VPS and share the Internet with my devices.

Comment: Details matter.    We can't help without more specific information and what you have tried.   If I were starting off, I might google Wireguard VPN to make a start.  Its also worth checking if the blocks are performed by domain name or routing - if its on domain name (which your post seems to imply), you may only need a solution to change your DNS.